# how to get attribute from within a http get response

Tags: jquery

I am getting a html response from a http get but unable to parse the returned value.

My script has `$.get(url, function(data, status) {`

data and status are good.

I get valid response for the http get and value of data is like this:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Some title</TITLE>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
</STYLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="mytitle" title="Some title value goes here"></div>
<p align="right"><i>&copy; 2012 My company Name. All Rights Reserved.</i></p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I would like to access the div with id mytitle and get title attribute. I have tried a few things and none seem to work. I have tried:

```
var k = data;
var m = $(k).find("esptitle").attr("title").text();
alert(m); // note alert(k) is same as data and works
other tries:
var m = k.find("esptitle").attr("title");

});
```

Appreciate any tips.. Many Thanks.

Comment: What is `esptitle` supposed to reference?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What is an "esptitle"? Such a thing does not exist anywhere in the HTML you've posted. If you're trying to find the element with the id `mytitle`, you need to use `$("#mytitle")` to select by id. Please read up on jQuery selectors, this is *extremely* basic jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`var m = $(k).find("esptitle").attr("title").text();` is the right way to do it conceptually, but `.find("esptitle")` tries to find  tags. You don't have this in your html and it is not an html tag anyway. If you are working with a framework or whatever that uses "esptitle" as keyword or xml tag in sever code, you should be aware that browsers and JavaScript don't have access to this code. They can only work with the generated html and css and whatever the server sends them when they make ajax requests.

You also can't call .text() on a result of .attr() because attr returns value of an attribute as string, which I guess is what you actually need.

The correct code would be:

```
var m = $(k).find("#mytitle").attr("title");
```